# Typescript error TS1005 from tinycolor declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript1.9

I'm converting a small project to TypeScript 1.9 to try to learn the language. I have been using a library called tinycolor, and I downloaded a declaration file for it.

The file can be viewed here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/tinycolor/tinycolor.d.ts

I am getting errors like

> C:\Users\kbirger\Documents\Projects\peysage\ts\typings\tinycolor\tinycolor.d.ts(339,9): error TS1005: ';' expected.

The relevant line of code is here:

```
declare namespace Readable {
    interface Readable {
        brightness: number;
        color: number;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. Looks like correct syntax to me, and what's more, I get no complaints when I run the thing through the playground on the TypeScript site.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: No issue with this definition file when compiling with TS 1.8

Comment: what command are you running in tsc 1.8? could they have changed syntax in 1.9? I'm new and I can't find any specific differences